# Вывод пользователей с самым большим rang

Tags: php

Например, у нас есть 5 пользователей Igrok_1,Igrok_2,Igrok_3,Igrok_4,Igrok_5.
Также у каждого пользователя есть rang, у Igrok_1 = 100 ,Igrok_2 = 200 , Igrok_3 = 300 , Igrok_4 = 400, Igrok_5 = 500 ! **Вопрос**, как вывести 2 пользователя у которых rang самый большой от большего к меньшему вот так:

1. Igrok_5 - 500
2. Igrok_4 - 400

Answer (score 2, accepted):

И так, у нас есть база данных mysql и в ней к примеру 2 поля igroki (те самые игроки) и  somenum(это их ранг)

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT igroki FROM numbers ORDER BY `somenum` DESC", $database);

while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $myrow['igroki']; //можешь еще добавить в запрос поле с рангом и вывести его.
}
```

Вроде должно работать, я не испытывал. Не судите строго)

Comment: Вы где-то в тексте увидели оговорку о mysql?

Comment: Пользователи!! Не представляю как это без баз данных будет выглядеть)

Comment: @LordyGL Вы разве не знали что есть сайты которым база данных не нужна?

Comment: @01011001101010011.. и где же тогда в этих сайтах хранятся пользователи и информация о них, если не в базе данных?

Comment: @Comfmore на почте. Не думайте что БД - это единственный способ хранения информации.

Comment: Ну да, извращенцы наверное тоже бывают

Answer (score 0):

игроки у тебя просто отдельные переменные? создай лучше массив, с ним удобнее работать, например, как уже сказали ранее, его можно отсортировать.

ну а если без массивов, то просто if'ом по очереди сравнивай значения (больше/меньше), но без массива это как-то тупо.

Answer (score -1):

Читайте про сортировку массива. Как сортировку реализуете, выводите первые два значения.